# extend onclick function

Tags: javascript

I have a onclick function like this

```
onclick = function(){alert('hello')}
```

I want to add an additional function to it base on the server response so that I can display more, like not only display hello but also 'you are welcome', how to writ this without jquery?

```
onclick = function(){alert('you are welcome')}
```

thank you for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

```
elementSelected.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert('you are welcome');
});
```

This is a modern way to do that.

For that old IE, you have to do this instead:

```
elementSelected.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
    alert('you are welcome');
});
```

---

So a more convenience way to do that is

```
function addEvent(ele, type, func){
    if(ele.addEventListener){
        ele.addEventListener(type, func, false);
    }else if(ele.attachEvent){
        ele.attachEvent("on" + type, func);
    }
}

addEvent(document.body, "click", function(){
    alert("Hello world!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using event listner's might do the trick ,but please note that the W3C model does not state which event handler is fired first.

I would better suggest you to check for the server response from within your function and call the second function from there.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery, add event listeners instead of using the onClick values.
Here's a [description](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
yourelement.attachEvent('onclick',hello);

Function hello(){
// do wat you want here
}
```